# Converting Rebol csv tool to Red

Tags: rebol, red

I started to convert http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=csv-tools.r from Rebol to Red; I'm stuck on "as-string" as-binary , can't find doc about them on Rebol.

```
    to-iso-date: func [
      "Convert a date to ISO format (Excel-compatible subset)"
      date [date!] /utc "Convert zoned time to UTC time"
    ] [
      if utc [date: date + date/zone date/zone: none] ; Excel doesn't support the Z suffix
      either date/time [ajoin [
        next form 10000 + date/year "-"
        next form 100 + date/month "-"
        next form 100 + date/day " "  ; ... or T
        next form 100 + date/time/hour ":"
        next form 100 + date/time/minute ":"
        next form 100 + date/time/second  ; ... or offsets
      ]] [ajoin [
        next form 10000 + date/year "-"
        next form 100 + date/month "-"
        next form 100 + date/day
      ]]
    ]

    to-csv: func [
      "Convert a block of values to a CSV-formatted line in a string."
      [catch]
      data [block!] "Block of values"
      delimiter [char! string! binary!] {Default ","}
      ; Empty delimiter, " or CR or LF may lead to corrupt data
    ][
      output: make block! 2 * length? data
      delimiter: either with [to-string delimiter] [","]
      unless empty? data [insert tail output format-field first data data: next data]
      foreach x data [insert insert tail output delimiter format-field get/any 'x]
      to-string output

      format-field: func [x [any-type!]] [case [
        any [not value? 'x error? get/any 'x] [throw-error 'script 'expect-set [
          [any-string! any-word! any-path! binary! scalar! date!] type? get/any 'x
        ]]
        none? :x [""]
        any-string? :x [ajoin [{"} replace/all copy x {"} {""} {"}]]
        :x == #"^(22)" [{""""}]  ; Weirdly, = and =? return true when x is 34
        char? :x [ajoin [{"} x {"}]]
        money? :x [find/tail form x "$"]
        scalar? :x [form x]
        date? :x [to-iso-date x]
        any [any-word? :x binary? :x any-path? :x] [
          ajoin [{"} replace/all to-string :x {"} {""} {"}]
        ]
        'else [throw-error 'script 'expect-set reduce [
          [any-string! any-word! any-path! binary! scalar! date!] type? :x
        ]]
      ]]
    ]

    load-csv: func [
      "Load and parse CSV-style delimited data. Returns a block of blocks."
      [catch]
      source [file! url! string! binary! block!] "File or url will be read"
      /binary "Don't convert the data to string (if it isn't already)"
      delimiter [char! string! binary!] {Default #","}
      /into "Insert into a given block, rather than make a new one"
      output [block!] "Block returned at position after the insert"
      /part "Get only part of the data, and set to the position afterwards"
      count [integer!] "Number of lines to return"
      after [any-word! none!] "Set to data at position after decoded part"
    ] [
      if block? source [ ; Many sources, load them all into the same output block
        unless into [output: make block! length? source]
        unless with [delimiter: ","]
        x: [file! url! string! binary!]
        foreach y source [
          unless find x type?/word y [
            cause-error 'script 'expect-set reduce [x type? :y]
          ]
          either binary [
            output: load-csv/binary/with/into y delimiter output
          ] [
            output: load-csv/with/into y delimiter output
          ]
        ]
        return either into [output] [head output]
      ]
      ; Read the source if necessary
      if any [file? source url? source] [throw-on-error [
        source: either binary [read/binary source] [read source]
      ]]
      unless binary [source: as-string source] ; No line conversion
      ; Use either a string or binary value emitter
      emit: either binary? source [:as-binary] [:as-string]
      ; Prep output and local vars
      unless into [output: make block! 1]
      line: [] val: make string! 0
      ; Parse rules
      valchars: remove/part charset [#"^(00)" - #"^(FF)"] crlf
      case [
        any [char? delimiter: any [delimiter ","] last? delimiter] [ ; One char
          valchars: compose [any (remove/part valchars delimiter)]
        ]
        empty? delimiter [throw-error 'script 'invalid-arg delimiter]
        'else [ ; Multi-character delimiter needs special handling
          remove/part valchars copy/part as-string delimiter 1
          valchars: compose/deep [any [
            some (valchars) | y: delimiter :y break | (first as-string delimiter)
          ]]
        ]
      ]
      value: [
        ; Value in quotes, with Excel-compatible handling of bad syntax
        {"} (clear val) x: [to {"} | to end] y: (insert/part tail val x y)
        any [{"} x: {"} [to {"} | to end] y: (insert/part tail val x y)]
        [{"} x: valchars y: (insert/part tail val x y) | end]
        (insert tail line emit copy val) |
        ; Raw value
        x: valchars y: (insert tail line emit copy/part x y)
      ]
      part: pick [ ; Rule must fail and go to the alternate in order to continue
        [end skip]  ; Will always fail, so the break won't be reached
        [(cont: if positive? count [count: count - 1 [end skip]]) cont]
        ; While count is positive, cont is set to [end skip], which will fail
        ; and go the alternate. Otherwise, cont is set to none, which will
        ; succeed, and then the subsequent break will stop the parsing.
        ; Parsing control flow can get a little convoluted at times in R2.
      ] not part
      ; as-string because R2 doesn't parse binary that well
      parse/all as-string source [z: any [
        end break | part break |
        (line: make block! length? line)
        value any [delimiter value] [crlf | cr | lf | end]
        (output: insert/only output line)
      ] z:]
      if after [set after either binary? source [as-binary z] [z]]
      also either into [output] [head output]
        (source: output: line: val: x: y: none) ; Free the locals
    ]
```

Comment: At first you should replace **funct** of the original script with **function**. You can probably omit all the as-string coercing and special handling of binary data, because Red handles binary data probably better than Rebol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as-string` and `as-binary` are Rebol3 specific functions to represent data in different format, i.e. `binary!` data as UTF-8 string. In Red, load data as your required format with `read` for string and `read/binary` for binary data.

You can also take a look at https://github.com/rebolek/red-tools/blob/master/csv.red for simple CSV encoder/decoder.

Comment: Rebol 2-specific. Are not in Rebol 3.